# NO ERRORS but the game keeps stopping and asks me to close it

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android based game development and I'm getting the following error but I can't find where the problem is and I'm going crazy !!!!

**Error Log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.scouts.simaphore, PID: 26196
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scouts.simaphore/com.scouts.simaphore.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1957)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.scouts.simaphore.MainActivity.newQuestion(MainActivity.java:166)
        at com.scouts.simaphore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1957) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26196 SIG: 9
Process 26196 terminated.
```

Comment: i,m using android studio to make a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

If I'm wrong, it seems your error log (Caused by) clearly says that it is due to the `NullPointerException`.

```java
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.scouts.simaphore.MainActivity.newQuestion(MainActivity.java:166)
        at com.scouts.simaphore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
```

- Handle the `NullPointerException` around the method `setImageResource`
- (OR) look into orgin of that particular field which is causing issue and correct it to send the right value to the method `setImageResource`